# How do I activate a Spring Boot profile when running from IntelliJ?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, gradle, spring-boot

I have 5 environments:

```
 - local (my development machine)
 - dev
 - qc
 - uat
 - live
 - staging
```

I want different application properties to be used for each environment, so I have the following properties files each which have a different URL for the datasource:

```
 - application.properties  (containing common properties)
 - application-local.properties
 - application-dev.properties
 - application-qc.properties
 - application-uat.properties
 - application-live.properties
```

I am using IntelliJ and running my app using bootRun in the Gradle plugin on my local machine.  I will be using deploying the same application war file on all other environments which run Tomcat.

I have tried adding:

> --spring.profiles.active=local

to the run configuration under script parameters.

I have tried adding

> -Dspring.profiles.active=local

to the run configuration under VM options.

Neither work. I keep seeing the INFO message on startup say: *No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default*

If I run my app from the windows command line using

```
gradle bootRun
```

but I first set the environment variable

```
set SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local
```

Then everything works.

So my question is, how do I activate my local spring boot profile when running bootRun from IntelliJ ?

Comment: Why are you running the application via gradle there? Wouldn't it be 10 times more convenient to use the run configuration?  There's a field where you can set the profiles to enable...

Comment: I am using the run configuration in IntelliJ, as explained above. It's not working.

Comment: No you're not. What I am talking about is the "Spring Boot run configuration" Run -> Edit configuration > New > Spring Boot.

Comment: Aah yes, I moved away from Spring Boot run configuration as I needed to expand project.properties into application.properties in my build.gradle and if I used the Spring Boot run configuration, it didn't seem to work. I'll look into resolving that issue and then perhaps I can simply use the active profile field as you suggested

Comment: Using the Spring Boot configuration seems more trouble than its worth. The 'Make' simply copies across the resources and doesn't filter/alter them as per by build script. Then telling it to run the 'build' from gradle instead of 'make' simply causes the run to freeze. If I use bootRun instead, along with my environment entry as per below answer, all works fine.

Comment: Done, although when I originally tried that in 2016 as mentioned in my original post, it wasn't working.  Whatever the issue was, it must have been fixed since.

Answer (score 455, accepted):

I added `-Dspring.profiles.active=test` to VM Options and then re-ran that configuration. It worked perfectly.

This can be set by

- Choosing `Run | Edit Configurations...`
- Go to the `Configuration` tab
- Expand the `Environment` section to reveal `VM options`

Comment: I was stuck in the same situation but for a Maven project. Thanks for the help.  We have set the VM option for each and every test file.

Comment: It doesn't work for me too. I use gradle and two modules (api and ui)

Comment: Doesn't work for me either, also using gradle here.

Comment: HI, I have the same issue but this fix does not fix the issue. what is meant here by reran the configuration? is it as just as rerunning the task?

Comment: I ran that particular test after editing it as shown.

Comment: any other ideas why its not picking up the profile in my case. In edit config, under VM options I set "-Dspring.profiles.active=dev". I have two file application-dev.properties and application-prod.properties under resources folder. But its not picking up.  I am using 2019 intellij version.

Comment: This works only for configurations of type "Application" (running the public static main method). It will not work if your configuration is of type maven or gradle (mvn spring-boot:run)

Comment: Usually, spring.profiles.include is preferrable, because spring.profiles.active also disables other profiles. Deactivating default profiles might be undesired.

Comment: Now you have to go to modify options. Then environment variables are available for change

Comment: for me, I found it like so: Run -> Edit configurations -> Modify options -> check the 'add VM options' to reveal it then you can add -Dspring.profiles.active=dev in the space provided for VM options

Comment: @HibaHasan you saved my day

Answer (score 137):

If you actually make use of Spring Boot run configurations (currently only supported in the Ultimate Edition) it's easy to pre-configure the profiles in "Active Profiles" setting.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure this would work, however I am not using the Spring Boot run configuration, I am using the Gradle run configuration which doesn't have the "Active Profiles" field. My gradle build filters and modifies some of the properties files it copies to the build directory, so I am using the Grade run configuration for this.

Comment: As an above answer pointed out: if this isn't working for you, ensure that you're passing in the `args` in your `Application.main()` eg `SpringApplication.run( Application.class, args );`

Comment: This feature is supported in the Ultimate edition only.

Comment: Thanks @JulienMalige for pointing this out. I will edit my answer.

Comment: You can use a comma separate list of them as you would in the cli so for example `default, staging`. The far right takes highest precedence so for example `foo=bar` (default) and  `foo=baz` (staging), will result in `foo=baz`

Answer (score 85):

**Tested with IntelliJ Community edition 2021.x**

You can create Multiple configurations, one each for a specific profile, In my case below, I have created a dev config with dev profile environment variable.

> 1. Goto Run > Edit Configuration
> 2. Choose the configuration you want to edit, in the left under Application.
> 3. On the right side > Under Environment Variable, update `spring.profiles.active=<your profile name>` **example
>    `spring.profiles.active=dev`**
>    ***(observer:- the variable should be without -D flag)***
> 4. Save the changes and Run the Spring boot app with the same configuration.

Note:- You can also create a new configuration or copy existing in step 2 above, using the option available in the same panel.

[image]

Comment: This answer worked for me, I'm using the gradle bootRun configuration on Spring Boot 2.4.2 and the other answers would not change my active profile. Thanks!

Comment: Only this one works for non-springboot app

Answer (score 48):

Spring Boot seems had changed the way of reading the VM options as it evolves. Here's some way to try when you launch an application in Intellij and want to active some profile:

#### 1. Change VM options

Open "Edit configuration" in "Run", and in "VM options", add: `-Dspring.profiles.active=local`

It actually works with one project of mine with `Spring Boot v2.0.3.RELEASE` and `Spring v5.0.7.RELEASE`, but not with another project with `Spring Boot v2.1.1.RELEASE` and `Spring v5.1.3.RELEASE`.

Also, when running with Maven or JAR, people mentioned this:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.profiles=dev
```

or

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev XXX.jar
```

(See here: [how to use Spring Boot profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060989/how-to-use-spring-boot-profiles))

#### 2. Passing JVM args

It is mentioned somewhere, that Spring changes the way of launching the process of applications if you specify some JVM options; it forks another process and will not pass the arg it received so this does not work. The only way to pass args to it, is:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="..."
```

Again, this is for Maven.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/run-debug.html

#### 3. Setting (application) env var

What works for me for the second project, was setting the environment variable, as mentioned in some answer above: "Edit configuration" - "Environment variable", and:

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local
```

Comment: The env var should actually be `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE`.

Comment: I added it in "Run configuration" of IDEA "VM options" like "spring.profiles.active" and it works. Maybe another form like urs is used system-wide in system properties?

Comment: If you're adding it to `~/.profile` or similar, you have to use `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` -- `spring.profiles.active` likely only works as an argument on the command line.

Comment: Ah.. so you mean the same as I suspected; real system env not just the application env. OK I make an edit.

Comment: This answer is very concise and complete

Answer (score 18):

Try add this command in your build.gradle

[image]

So for running configure that shape:

[image]

Comment: doesn't work for me

Answer (score 11):

I ended up adding the following to my build.gradle:

```
bootRun {
  environment SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: environment.SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE ?: "local"
}

test {
  environment SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: environment.SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE ?: "test"
}
```

So now when running bootRun from IntelliJ, it defaults to the "local" profile.

On our other environments, we will simply set the 'SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE' environment variable in Tomcat.

I got this from a comment found here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/592

Answer (score 11):

For [Spring Boot 2.1.0](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/run-profiles.html) and later you can use

`mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=foo,bar`

Comment: In your commandline will be `spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=local`

Comment: with spring-boot:run this is the answer

Answer (score 6):

A probable cause could be that you do not pass the command line parameters into the applications main method. I made the same mistake some weeks ago.

```
public static final void main(String... args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and suggestion, however I am passing the arguments in.

Comment: This actually fixed my problem. For some reason when I created the project using Gradle, it didn't auto-generate my `Application` class so  did it by hand from memory. Missed the `args` step, and so the "Active Profiles" box in the run configuration didn't work -- I had to manually pass in `-Dspring.profiles.active` in the VM options box.

Answer (score 3):

I use the Intellij Community Edition.
Go to the "Run/Debug Configurations" > Runner tab > Environment variables > click button "...". Add:
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE = local

[spring.profiles.active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuVgy.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

In my case I used below configuration at VM options in `IntelliJ` , it was not picking the local configurations but after a restart of `IntelliJ` it picked configuration details from `IntelliJ` and service started running.

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=local
```

Answer (score 3):

So for resuming...

If you have the IntelliJ Ultimate the correct answer is the one provided by [Daniel Bubenheim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39775038/13424840)

But if you don't, create in Run->Edit Configurations and in Configuration tab add the next Environment variable:

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=profilename
```

And to execute the jar do:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=profilename XXX.jar
```

Answer (score 3):

This is worked for me *Intellij Ultimate version 2022.3*.

#### ===== Step 1 =====

go to **Run > Edit Configurations**
[image]

#### ===== Step 2 =====

first I created a **dev** profile using ***application-dev.properties*** file in *resources* directory.
you can see below popup window.
[image]

#### ===== Step 3 =====

Now click click **Modify Option** section under ***Build and run*** section to enable *Environmental variables*.

#### OR

simple you can use **ALT + E** shortcut for that.
[image]

#### ===== Step 4 =====

Now you can see like below and you can enable spring profiles(in this *dev* profile) using ***SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev***.
[image]

Click on ***apply*** and ***ok*** and run the application.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Replace your profile name with BE]

You can try the above way to activate a profile

Answer (score 1):

VM option is hidden by default.
Here is the right way to do it

Run->Edit Configurations->Select the application on the left menu->Add VM Options
[image]

and then add

-Dspring.profiles.active=<profile_name>

Replace the <profile_name> with the profile, say *local*

Click Apply & OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Edit your build.gradle file as followed.

```
ext { profile = project.hasProperty('profile') ? project['profile'] : 'local' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 ways

1. Using gradle project property

In build.gradle, add

```
bootRun{
//https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/592#issuecomment-880263914
    if (project.hasProperty('profiles')) {
        environment SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: profiles
    } else {
        def profiles = 'dev'
        environment SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: profiles
    }
}
```

In intellij gradle configuration, change the value "test" in "-Pprofiles" as appropriate to environment you want to run

[image]

2. Using environment property

Follow answer by @Hubert https://stackoverflow.com/a/39749545/3333878

And configure the run configuration as

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create files properties like these

```
application.properties
application-dev.properties
application-prod.properties
```

then run

[image]

Comment: How can I enable this 'Active profiles' option as I can't see it by default.

Comment: When you put application / compiled source code to environment A, profile default is A. When you put application / compiled source code to environment B, profile default is B.

Comment: Functionality with 'active profiles' is enabled only on IDEA Ultimate version. On community version there is not possible to set like that.

Answer (score -5):

Set `-Dspring.profiles.active=local` under program arguments.

Comment: I have removed the quotes from my question above.  I am not actually using quotes, I was just trying to show exactly what I was putting into the run configuration fields

Comment: you mean VM options!

Comment: This answer is very misleading as program arguments won't be recognized by the application!

Comment: This answer will not work, as mentioned by other folks, it should be under VM Options in IntelliJ Idea and not in the program arguments