# How to access environment variable externally in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot

Is it possible to access environment variable of different application.properties from a single place. Actually we are building this software where we have different application.properties for different projects like user-asset. So is it possible to have all environment variable at one external place. If yes, how will it be accessed?

Comment: if you speak about multiple applications you can do it with spring-cloud-config. Else your question should be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

You would have an application.properties file that defines variables that would never change in what every situation you have.

## application.properties

```
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=true #Just an example
```

Then you could have a separate application.properties with a different name such as **application-active.properties**. This file would add onto the base **application.properties** file.

## application-active.properties

```
example.enviroment.variable=${I_AM_AN_ENVIROMENT_VARIABLE}
```

Then you could have a different application.properties file that has the same property name, in this case `example.enviroment.variable`.

## application-dev.properties

```
example.enviroment.variable=${I_AM_A_DIFFERENT_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE}
```

Then in your code, you would just need to grab the example.enviroment.variable property depending on the current profile and it would grab the correct environment variable.

To specify what application.properites look at [using profiles in spring-boot.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060989/how-to-use-spring-boot-profiles)

Answer (score 0):

If its an environment variable, then I think multiple applications can access the same variable.

But if its inside the application.properties file, then I think its not possible.

Not only that, if you really feel that one application needs to access the application.properties of another, then I believe this is not a right way to proceed.

Rather, you should externalize the configurations (maybe by using a config server like spring-cloud-config) and share the common properties between the applications.