# Spring boot Custom Properties

Tags: java, spring-boot

in my project there are 2 resource properties

**1. application.properties**

```
server.port=8002

spring.data.mongodb.host=
spring.data.mongodb.port=
spring.data.mongodb.database=
spring.data.mongodb.username=
spring.data.mongodb.password=
```

**2. application-development.properties**

```
server.port=8002

spring.data.mongodb.host=
spring.data.mongodb.port=
spring.data.mongodb.database=
spring.data.mongodb.username=
spring.data.mongodb.password=

spring.data.solr.host
```

this class uses the value properties of development

```
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories(basePackages = {
    "id.alfadigital.alfagift.service.product.v1.db.solr.repository",
    "id.alfadigital.alfagift.service.product.v2.db.solr.repository"
})
public class SolrConfiguration {

  @Value("${spring.data.solr.host}")
  private String solrUrl;

  @Bean
  public SolrClient solrClient() {
    return new HttpSolrClient.Builder(solrUrl).build();
  }

  @Bean
  public SolrTemplate solrTemplate(SolrClient client) {
    return new SolrTemplate(client);
  }
}
```

> I use **application-development.properties** as my project resoure

so I run the project with the following command :

`mvn spring-boot:run -D spring.profiles.active=development`

but an error is attached when I run the project

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solrConfiguration': 
           Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
           Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.data.solr.host' in value "${spring.data.solr.host}"
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.data.solr.host' in value "${spring.data.solr.host}"
```

I'm confused, where are my mistakes, and how should I do?

Comment: Have you check, if your application is running under the development profile. It seems it is not. If you got to the beginning of the spring logs you can see the active profile.

Comment: Is there actually a value for that property in your dev config? Because in the property file you shared, there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please run your application with following command. Because of wrong use of command it's not able to pick up the `development` profile.

`mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=development`

Example:
[how to use Spring Boot profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060989/how-to-use-spring-boot-profiles)

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have the correct file name `application-development.properties` and correct Java Opts `-Dspring.profiles.active=development`, you must also place the profile specific properties file alongside with `application.properties`

> Profile-specific properties are loaded from the same locations as standard application.properties

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.12.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your properties file matches up with the name of your Spring profile as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties).

That is, if you are running from a "development" profile, Spring should pick up the `application-development.properties` file (or `application-development.yml`).

Then in your `application.properties` file you can specify your profile by using `spring.profiles.active=development`. Or you can specify the profile from the command line using `-Dprofile` as you mention.

As mentioned in in the link, "*If several profiles are specified, a last-wins strategy applies. For example, profiles specified by the spring.profiles.active property are added after those configured through the SpringApplication API and therefore take precedence.*"

But also note that in your shared code you have no value for your *spring.data.solr.host* property.