# Injecting filed value using @Value() in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, environment-variables

So I have some custom POJO. I want any time when I instantiate that object thorough empty constructor to have its filed `fee` initialized to some preset value from `application.properties`.

In my `application-prod.properties`:

```
fee=1500
```

My POJO class:

```
public class PenaltyWithNoInvoiceDto {
    
    private int penatltyId; 
    private int number; 
    private String projectName;
    
    @Value("${fee}")
    private float fee;
    
    public PenaltyWithNoInvoiceDto() {
        
    }
    
    public PenaltyWithNoInvoiceDto(int penatltyId, int number, String projectName) {
        super();
        this.penatltyId = penatltyId;
        this.number = number;
        this.projectName = projectName;
    }
}
```

In my `@Service` class, I'm instantiating `PenaltyWithNoInvoiceDto`with empty constructor. But when I print `fee` field, I get zero.

How do I make this field to have value of 1500, I get that value from `application-prod.properties`?

Comment: You have to start your application with prod profile. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060989/how-to-use-spring-boot-profiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@Value` annotation will only be applied when Spring is managing the lifecycle of the bean - for example when the bean is annotated with `@Component`, `@Service`, etc or instantiated by a `@Bean` method of an `@Configuration` class. It won't be applied when you do `new PenaltyWithNoInvoiceDto()` in your own code.

You could add the `@Value("${fee}")` to a field of your `@Service` class and then pass it to the DTO when instantiating it with something like `new PenaltyWithNoInvoiceDto(fee)`.