# using @Profile in java spring for disabling some features

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml

My requirement is, when i build a project with 'dev' profile(mvn clean install -Pdev) on that time I need to disable some of the features. if profile is not 'dev' then no need to remove those features.
this my root pom.xml,

```
<profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <modules>
            <module>../cmn/module1</module>
            <module>../cmn/module2</module>
            <module>../cmn/module3</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
```

i have to disable some features on module3(this having separate pom.xml).
and I am pasting here Sample feature that needs to be disabled when profile is 'dev',

```
@Configuration
public class Sample{
}
```

I came to know that @Profile is the right annotation to disable some features, and then I have modified the class to something like the below,

```
@Configuration
@Profile("!dev")
public class Sample{
}
```

'!dev' means this feature is disabled for profile 'dev', other than 'dev' it should be enabled.
but with @Profile("!dev") the feature is not disabled. i have build the project with 'mvn clean install -Pdev'. still the project has the feature Sample.

what is wrong with me? how can I disable the Sample feature when my project is build with 'dev' profile?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060989/how-to-use-spring-boot-profiles

Comment: what version of spring are you using?

Comment: @Paplusc Spring version is 5.2.3

Comment: did you try this? `mvn clean install -Pdev -DprofileIdEnabled=true`

Comment: @Paplus No, I have not tried 'mvn clean install -Pdev -DprofileIdEnabled=true'. but meantime I don't want this as well. i don't want touch with maven command.