# SpringBoot: running with a specified profile has no effect

Tags: spring-boot

After generating a simple web app using [Spring initializr](https://start.spring.io/), I created 2 YML files in `src/main/resources` folder:

- `application.yml`
- `application-prod.yml`

and added 2 different values inside each of them:

```yaml
# application-prod.yml
app:
  name: demo-prod

#application.yml
app:
  name: demo-local
```

Then I built the app with `mvn clean install -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -DskipTests`.
And started the app with `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=prod`.

Looking at the log lines of the startup, I can see that there was no active profile defined and Spring will fall back to the default one:

```
No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default`
```

What am I missing, why Spring didn't see my profile `prod` passed in from the CLI?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use Spring Boot profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060989/how-to-use-spring-boot-profiles)

Comment: Also: [Setting active profile and config location from command line in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038250/setting-active-profile-and-config-location-from-command-line-in-spring-boot)

Comment: in short, in spring boot 2.0+ the parameter with maven is called `spring-boot.run.profiles`

Comment: @eis: running as you suggested `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles.active=prod` had no effects.

Comment: I did not suggest that? please re-read what I suggested :) (or see the links I provided)

Comment: The following worked for me: `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=prod` displaying clearly that the profile `prod` was active: `The following profiles are active: prod`. Thank you guys!