# Spring Boot active profile not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit

Spring 2.4.5.

Trying to run test examples.

```
2022-06-30 21:58:39.897  INFO   --- [    Test worker] .b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper : Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [dataset.status.dashboard.api.repository.StatusRepositoryIntegrationTest], using SpringBootContextLoader
2022-06-30 21:58:39.901  INFO   --- [    Test worker] o.s.t.c.support.AbstractContextLoader    : Could not detect default resource locations for test class [dataset.status.dashboard.api.repository.StatusRepositoryIntegrationTest]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
2022-06-30 21:58:39.902  INFO   --- [    Test worker] t.c.s.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils : Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [dataset.status.dashboard.api.repository.StatusRepositoryIntegrationTest]: StatusRepositoryIntegrationTest does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
2022-06-30 21:58:39.961  INFO   --- [    Test worker] .b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper : Found @SpringBootConfiguration company.status.dashboard.api.App for test class dataset.status.dashboard.api.repository.StatusRepositoryIntegrationTest
2022-06-30 21:58:40.013  INFO   --- [    Test worker] .b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper : Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener]
2022-06-30 21:58:40.022  INFO   --- [    Test worker] .b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper : Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@5be3295e, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@48ec863b, org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener@37762e2a, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@4db30010, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@f586921, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@23a9fbaf, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@2528968e, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@70cea1bb, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener@3c93dfe2, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@500b2f5c, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@31f64f35, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@3430e3c9, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@16fe5662, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener@1f06ea2e, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@1c8a911c]
2022-06-30 21:58:40.025  INFO   --- [    Test worker] .b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper : Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [dataset.status.dashboard.api.repository.StatusRepositoryIntegrationTest$FindFirstDailyDeliveryStatusesByDatasetUnitWithinTimeRange], using SpringBootContextLoader
2022-06-30 21:58:40.025  INFO   --- [    Test worker] o.s.t.c.support.AbstractContextLoader    : Could not detect default resource locations for test class [dataset.status.dashboard.api.repository.StatusRepositoryIntegrationTest$FindFirstDailyDeliveryStatusesByDatasetUnitWithinTimeRange]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
2022-06-30 21:58:40.026  INFO   --- [    Test worker] t.c.s.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils : Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [dataset.status.dashboard.api.repository.StatusRepositoryIntegrationTest$FindFirstDailyDeliveryStatusesByDatasetUnitWithinTimeRange]: FindFirstDailyDeliveryStatusesByDatasetUnitWithinTimeRange does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
2022-06-30 21:58:40.027  INFO   --- [    Test worker] .b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper : Found @SpringBootConfiguration company.status.dashboard.api.App for test class dataset.status.dashboard.api.repository.StatusRepositoryIntegrationTest$FindFirstDailyDeliveryStatusesByDatasetUnitWithinTimeRange
2022-06-30 21:58:40.029  INFO   --- [    Test worker] .b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper : Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener]
2022-06-30 21:58:40.029  INFO   --- [    Test worker] .b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper : Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@14f0dd2a, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@6c6b8304, org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener@370431a5, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@491f8897, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@5b140513, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@6b57ced6, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@7dc84300, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@48a6371e, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener@33e18f84, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@6695c650, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@59fa49c1, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@201d9b27, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@1f3fbd0f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener@57d05ffe, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@5cefa084]
2022-06-30 21:58:40.183  INFO 69695 --- [    Test worker] .StatusRepositoryIntegrationTest : Starting StatusRepositoryIntegrationTest using Java 11.0.15 on C12346 with PID 69695 (started by alex in /Users/alex/projects/status-dashboard-api)
2022-06-30 21:58:40.183  INFO 69695 --- [    Test worker] .StatusRepositoryIntegrationTest : The following profiles are active: local
```

Configuration for tests is being taken from `main.java.resources.application-local.properties`, whereas it must be taken from `test.java.resources` folder.

I tried different options `SPRING.PROFILES.ACTIVE`, `spring.profiles.active`, `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` with value `test` in IntelliJ Idea's `Run/Debug Configurations` window but it did help.

Test I want to run has the following annotations:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = {"classpath:application-integration.properties"})
class StatusRepositoryIntegrationTest {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`spring.profiles.active` is means what will be currently active if you not configurated another. If you would like to run with another profile, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060989/how-to-use-spring-boot-profiles).

Of course, if you configurate another profile, you have to `application-<profile_name>.properties/yml`

You don't need `@TestPropertySource` because Spring will find it under test and main folders. If there are two files with the same name in the main and in the test, I have noticed that they overwrite each other. *I did not test whether the configuration is overridden as a complete file or only extend by test.*

If you only want to run a test or apply a setting to a specific profile, then you need a @ActiveProfile("profile").

To learn more about profiles, read [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles).

**If we look at the example mentioned.**

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfile("integration")
class StatusRepositoryIntegrationTest { ... }
```

mvn/gradle test command `-Dspring.profiles.active=integration` or `--spring.profiles.active=integration`