# Spring profile unable to parse correct file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-profiles

This is the code that I'm using to reading the application.properties file in a gradle project.

```
@PropertySource("${spring.profiles.active}/application.properties")
```

My file is located inside `resources/local/application.properties`

This is how I'm trying to run the application in IntelliJ

[image]

This is the error that I end up getting.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.example.core.Application]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.profiles.active' in value "${spring.profiles.active}/application.properties"
```

Can someone help me fix this and read the correct config.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to get **spring.profiles.active** but in Intellij you're setting **spring.active.profiles**

Comment: I fixed this it still doesn't work. I get the following error ```org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.example.core.Application]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.active.profiles' in value "${spring.active.profiles}/application.properties"```

Comment: I think you swapped the names, try spring.profiles.active for more info check [this link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)

Comment: I've tried all possible combinations. It doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried setting it in Arguments or Environment variables instead of in VMoptions?

Comment: @MelissaStewart please take a look into [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738901/how-do-i-activate-a-spring-boot-profile-when-running-from-intellij) I think it can help you too