# Spring boot profiles and @Value

Tags: java, spring-boot, profile

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but I have the following value that points to the URL of a micro service.

```
@Value("${url.dispenseRoot}")
private String dispenseRoot;
```

And I am setting up my dev profile in my application.yml file such:

```
---
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test
    username: sa
    password: sa
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: dev

mpesa:
  host: sandbox.safaricom.co.ke
  port: 443

url:
  dispenseRoot: https://localhost:8844/dispense
---
```

Then, in accordance with my answer here: [How do I activate a Spring Boot profile when running from IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738901/how-do-i-activate-a-spring-boot-profile-when-running-from-intellij/44374099#44374099), I set up the spring boot profile on the run configuration as such:

[image]

And then run the following test to test my configuration:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class PaymentApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

And I get:

```
    ... 111 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'url.dispenseRoot' in value "${url.dispenseRoot}"
```

Now, if I copy and paste the following lines:

```
url:
  dispenseRoot: https://localhost:8844/dispense
```

Above my profile where I'm setting up the general settings that are true for everything, it works fine. Therefore, I'm certain it has something to do with profiles, but I can't figure out what it is.

Please advise...

Comment: The file name of your properties  is wrong. It should be application-dev.yml

Comment: could you clarify what you mean with "Above my profile where I'm setting up the general settings that are true for everything" ?

Comment: Your tests are probably run with a test-profile, meaning you need a separate properties-file in your `test/resources` dir. Be warned that the `@Value` annotation doesn't work for unit tests, so if you need to populate the field you have to do it via reflection.