# It is not possible to activate the Spring boot profile when starting from IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I can't activate the Spring download profile in IntelliJ IDEA.

Java 17

IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3 Beta (Ultimate Edition)

```
<spring.version>5.3.9</spring.version>
```

I'm coming in Run | Edit Configurations...
and in VM options I prescribe

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=development
```

And when you start the application from the IDE, the following error crashes:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class VM
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: VM
```

At the same time, I managed to launch it manually with this option:

```
java -jar main-ms-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.profiles.active=development
```

What else do I need to register in the IDE that I missed?
I cleaned the cache. Rechecked all the settings. Nothing helps. I don't understand what the problem might be. At the same time, other project developers do not have this problem. With the -Spring.profiles.active=development flag, the application is launched in IDEA

profile in Pom.xml
This is a shared file Pom.xml, which is at the root of the entire project on microservices.

```html
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>development</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <build.profile.id>development</build.profile.id>
        <maven.file.path>file:${project.basedir}/../../../maven</maven.file.path>
        <releases.maven.repository.url>${maven.file.path}/releases</releases.maven.repository.url>
        <snapshots.maven.repository.url>${maven.file.path}/snapshots
        </snapshots.maven.repository.url>
        <docker.registry.domain>localhost:5000</docker.registry.domain>
        <docker.registry.url>http://${docker.registry.domain}</docker.registry.url>
      </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And this is the file pom.xml the microservice I'm trying to run.

```html
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.asvoip.ump</groupId>
      <artifactId>ump-it-lib</artifactId>
      <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.asvoip.ump</groupId>
      <artifactId>ump-currencymanager-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.asvoip.ump</groupId>
      <artifactId>ump-sqldbclient-lib</artifactId>
      <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.asvoip.ump</groupId>
      <artifactId>ump-restapiserver-lib</artifactId>
      <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.asvoip.ump</groupId>
      <artifactId>ump-documentation-lib</artifactId>
      <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>co.elastic.logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-ecs-encoder</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
        <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

[image]
[image]

File application.yaml

```
spring.config.activate.on-profile: development
```

Comment: Hello. Please see: [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676) Use [edit] option and translate it to English OR move it (delete it from here and repost in proper place) to appropriate StackExchange site which is using your language (if such exists - visit first link in this comment to find list of sites about programming problems in other languages).

Comment: Why do you use `-Dspring.profiles.active=development` as the VM options but you use `--spring.profiles.active=development` in command line as the argument? The command line argumentas are specified in Run/Debug Configurations | **Program arguments:** field in the IDE.

Comment: Because in similar questions on this site, it is recommended to use VM options -Spring.profiles.active=development
And on the command line, by trial and error, I managed to launch the application with the --spring.profiles.active=development option. I tried using this option in VM, but nothing came out of it

Comment: can you push the project in GitHub and share the link for the same?

Comment: can you please try with the environment variable SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=development in IntelliJ

Comment: I added pom.xml is this it?

Comment: This should work if you put the `-Dspring.profiles.active=development` argument in the VM options section. In addition, if you use the spring boot run configuration, there is an "Active profiles" section at the bottom. So, if you're still experiencing problems, there's something else wrong, and we need more information such as a screenshot of your run configuration in IntelliJ.

Comment: I added a picture. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: I don't understand what configuration you are talking about. Information from the pom.xml I provided. I run the project using IDEA tools. I run only this microservice for execution. Please write in more detail what configuration you need.

Comment: You are mixing Spring Boot profiles and Maven profiles. What do you want to do?

Comment: And added a description that this is a shared file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39775038/8312604

Answer (score 2):

The Profile you define in your pom.xml is a maven build profile, which has nothing to do with a spring config-property profile.

maven-profile:https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html
spring-profile: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.x/reference/html/features.html#features.profiles

`spring.config.activate.on-profile: development` turns the current document of the configuration off if none of the active profiles is named `development`. So, this is like a filter for config-properties.

And you don't have to tell spring all profiles that will be used. So that line makes only sense if the document contains some application properties you want to turn on or off.
These profiles are controlled via the launch configuration in IntelliJ.

For the maven-profile, you can enable/disable them in IntelliJs maven tab.
See: [Work with maven profiles](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-profiles.html#declare_maven_profiles)

Comment: You can add settings there. But all my settings are the same as yours. I added information from the application file.yaml, where the profile is specified. I specified the IDEA version, it is the most recent.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the latest Intellij Ultimate has changed the UI. I normally set the active profile from `Edit Configuration > under Enviromnet > Active Profile` (for 2020 Intellij version), put your profile name there, and save it. remove `-Dspring.profiles.active=development` and then try

make sure you have a spring property file with the name `application-development.properties` or `application-development.yml` in your project