# Spring boot configuration file(yml) error with environment variables

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, mariadb, environment-variables, config

[image]
[image]

There is a problem with the formatting of the source code, but it has not been modified no matter how much I try, so I captured and uploaded the post. I would appreciate your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738901/how-do-i-activate-a-spring-boot-profile-when-running-from-intellij). There is explained how to configure IntelliJ environment variables and profiles correctly.